# cakephp displaying posted form data

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, post

I'm new to cakephp and trying to simply display form data once it is posted. I would like to type something on "add.ctp" which then redirects to "index.ctp" where the information I just typed should be displayed.

The reason why I'm doing this is because I like to echo my variables and forms at various places throughout my program for debugging purposes. I tend to work a lot with data that needs to be converted or manipulated so I like to check and make sure each part is doing its job correctly. I'm new to cakephp so I'm just trying to figure out how I can do this.

Here is the code for add.ctp where the information is entered.

```
View\Mysorts\add.ctp

<h1>Add Numbers</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Mysort');
echo $this->Form->input('original');
echo $this->Form->end('Add Numbers');
?>
```

Here is my function in the controller

```
Controller\MysortsController.php

<?php

class MysortsController extends AppController {
  public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

  public function index() {
         $this ->set('mysorts', $this->Mysort->find('all'));  

  } 

    public function add() {
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
        Configure::read();
        pr($this->data); //attempting to print posted information
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
 }

 function isempty(){
           $mysorts = $this->Mysort->find('all');
           $this->set('mysorts', $mysorts);
  }
}
?>
```

And finally, here is my index file where I would like to display the posted information.

```
View\Mysorts\index.ctp

<h1>Sorted Entries</h1>
<?php
 echo $this->Html->link("Add List", array('controller'=>'mysorts', 'action' => 'add'));
   if (!empty($mysorts)) {
  ?>
 <table>
   <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Original</th>
       <th>Sorted</th>
   </tr>

  <?php  foreach ($mysorts as $mysort): ?>
         <tr>
             <td><?php echo $mysort['Mysort']['id']; ?></td>
             <td>
                 <?php echo $mysort['Mysort']['original']; ?>
             </td>
             <td> <?php echo $mysort['Mysort']['sorted']; ?>
             </td>
         </tr>
   <?php endforeach;
         } else {
        echo '<p>No results found!</p>';
        }
   ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: Where is the index function of your controller? You'll have to set mysort for your index.ctp.

Comment: I thought the function had to share the name of the view page. My function is add and the view is add.ctp. Does the form name (in the view) also have to have the name of the function?

Answer (score 2):

If the code you have posted is the exact you are using that could not work at all.

1. You do not save the data you receive while being in the "add" method. This is done by **$this->ModelName->save($data)** where **ModelName** is the Model to use (in your case it should be *MySort* and **$data** is the posted data.
2. You are using Cakephp2.x? I assume so cause you are using **$this->request->is('post')** which was not there in 1.3, i think. The problem about that is, that the posted data is not stored in **$this->data** anymore. It is in **$this->request->data**.
3. Do not use **pr()**. It is too "dangerous" to forget something like that in the code. Use **debug()** instead. The output will be disabled as soon as you see the **DEBUG** constant in *Config/core.php* in your application root to **0**.
4. Calling the **redirect()** method in a controller generates a real 301 redirect. Which means the old output is dumped and lost. That and point 1 makes clear why you can not see anything. Nothing is saved and before you see the output of pr() your browser gets redirected. If you want to debug something use an **exit;** afterwards to make sure you wont miss the output. Sometimes you do not need it, but if you can not find your output, use it ;)

Hope this helps you.

Greetings

func0der

Comment: The code I have posted works (as far as the table displaying when there is data present), however, my question is in regards to the flow of information. If you look in my "index.ctp" file I check if $mysorts is empty, which is located in MysortsController.php. Does this break the MVC flow because I'm using the view to check something in the controller?

Comment: It does not break the MVC pattern if you check if an var is empty in the view.
You have to this to avoid php warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is something like this.
For your add.ctp you define the action you want your post.

```
<h1>Add Numbers</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create(array('action' => 'view'));
echo $this->Form->input('original');
echo $this->Form->end('Add Numbers');
?>
```

For your Controller You'll need to set the variable you want in your view

```
public function add() {

}

public function index(){
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->set('mysorts', $this->request->data);
    }

}
```

And I'm not sure if what I see in your index.ctp makes sense.

Comment: I have my index set up so if there is no data in my table it displays "No results found." Otherwise it displays the results. Did I do something incorrectly? It does exactly what I explained although I could be breaking the MVC structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your point is in trying to print something and then redirecting immediately? You won't see it when it redirects.

Anyhow, since your Form probably does not consist of a representation of an actual model, you might want to inspect your `$this->params['form']` variable as opposed to the normal `$this->data` that you would use in a FormHelper.

Also, do you realize you are missing a closing } in your Controller\MysortsController.php? It closes the add() function but not the class...

Comment: The reason why I'm doing this is because I tend to do a lot of calculations and data manipulation (with regular php), and I like to echo the current state of my variables and inputs throughout the processes for debugging purposes. I'm new to cakephp and just trying to figure out the basics of displaying data and overall flow.